# How to create in php: 2 colors table rows with 3 colors font

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

i need help, i have code like this

```html
<doctype html>
<html>
<table width="50%" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0"> 
<?php 

for($i = 1; $i <= 200; $i++) {
 if (($i % 2) == 1) {
  $tabel = "#8FBC8F"; 
 }
 else 
  $tabel = "#90EE90"; {
 echo '<tr bgcolor="' . $tabel . '"><td> <font color="blue">' . $i . '</font></td></tr>'; 
 } 
}
?> 
</html>
```

but i want to be like this: 
table with 2 colors table rows, and 3 colors font, with loop iteration.
what should i do with code?

maybe I should make this font color into 3 conditions (blue, red, yellow). but I do not know how the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing colours for lines and font:-

```
<doctype html>
<html>
<table width="50%" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0"> 
<?php 

for($i = 1; $i <= 200; $i++) 
{
    echo '<tr bgcolor="' . (($i % 2) ? "#8FBC8F" : "#90EE90") . '"><td> <font color="'.((($i % 3) == 0) ? 'blue' : ((($i % 3) == 1) ? 'yellow' : 'red' ) ).'">' . $i . '</font></td></tr>'; 
}
?> 
</html>
```

Although you might be better trying to do this in CSS.

EDIT

Following your comment.

Below is using nested if statements. Quite verbose. Basically one outer if to check is $i is divisible by 2. Then within that checking whether it is divisible by 3, or what the remainder is

```
<doctype html>
<html>
<table width="50%" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0"> 
<?php 

for($i = 1; $i <= 200; $i++) 
{
    if (($i % 2) == 0)
    {
        if (($i % 3) == 0)
        {
            echo '<tr bgcolor="#90EE90"><td> <font color="blue">' . $i . '</font></td></tr>'; 
        }
        else
        {
            if (($i % 3) == 1)
            {
                echo '<tr bgcolor="#90EE90"><td> <font color="yellow">' . $i . '</font></td></tr>'; 
            }
            else
            {
                echo '<tr bgcolor="#90EE90"><td> <font color="red">' . $i . '</font></td></tr>'; 
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (($i % 3) == 0)
        {
            echo '<tr bgcolor="#8FBC8F"><td> <font color="blue">' . $i . '</font></td></tr>'; 
        }
        else
        {
            if (($i % 3) == 1)
            {
                echo '<tr bgcolor="#8FBC8F"><td> <font color="yellow">' . $i . '</font></td></tr>'; 
            }
            else
            {
                echo '<tr bgcolor="#8FBC8F"><td> <font color="red">' . $i . '</font></td></tr>'; 
            }
        }
    }
}
?> 
</html>
```

You could use non nested if statements, but then you may as well just use a switch:-

```
<doctype html>
<html>
<table width="50%" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0"> 
<?php 

for($i = 1; $i <= 200; $i++) 
{
    switch (true)
    {
        case ($i % 2) == 0 AND ($i % 3) == 0:
            echo '<tr bgcolor="#90EE90"><td> <font color="blue">' . $i . '</font></td></tr>'; 
            break;
        case ($i % 2) == 0 AND ($i % 3) == 1:
            echo '<tr bgcolor="#90EE90"><td> <font color="yellow">' . $i . '</font></td></tr>'; 
            break;
        case ($i % 2) == 0 AND ($i % 3) == 2:
            echo '<tr bgcolor="#90EE90"><td> <font color="red">' . $i . '</font></td></tr>'; 
            break;
        case ($i % 2) == 1 AND ($i % 3) == 0:
            echo '<tr bgcolor="#8FBC8F"><td> <font color="blue">' . $i . '</font></td></tr>'; 
            break;
        case ($i % 2) == 1 AND ($i % 3) == 1:
            echo '<tr bgcolor="#8FBC8F"><td> <font color="yellow">' . $i . '</font></td></tr>'; 
            break;
        case ($i % 2) == 1 AND ($i % 3) == 2:
            echo '<tr bgcolor="#8FBC8F"><td> <font color="red">' . $i . '</font></td></tr>'; 
            break;
        default:
            // This should never happen
            break;
    }
}
?> 
</html>
```

You could also save the need for any explicit if / switch statement and just set up a couple of arrays, and calculate the modulus to use as the subscript for the array. This has the advantage of being compact and also easily expanded:-

```
<doctype html>
<html>
<table width="50%" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0"> 
<?php 

$bgcolor_array(0=>"#90EE90", 1=>"#8FBC8F");
$font_array(0=>"#blue", 1=>"#yellow", 2=>"#red");

for($i = 1; $i <= 200; $i++) 
{
    echo '<tr bgcolor="'.$bgcolor_array[($i % 2)].'"><td> <font color="'.$font_array[($i % 3)].'">' . $i . '</font></td></tr>'; 
}
?> 
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the codes Kickstart, Guilherme Ferreira,  sgt BOSE. I really appreciate it.
But in this case I want to understand how to use the "if condition" is.
And would you give the above solution to provide code examples in the use of a nested/multiple "if else" and explain it? thanks for all of you

Comment: I have added a few more examples and a small amount of explanation. Hopefully the other examples will give you some ideas of what style you like / don't like.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
$j = 1;
for($i = 1; $i <= 200; $i++) {
    if (($i % 2) == 1) {
        $tabel = "#8FBC8F"; 
    }
    else 
        $tabel = "#90EE90"; 

    if($j == 1) {
        $col = "blue";
    } else if ($j == 2) {
        $col = "red";   
    } else {
        $col = "yellow";
        $j = 1;
    }
    echo '<tr bgcolor="' . $tabel . '"><td> <font color="'.$col.'">' . $i . '</font></td></tr>'; 
    $j++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that easily way:

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 200; $i++) {
    if (($i % 2) == 0)
        $table = "#8FBC8F"; 
    else
        $table = "#90EE90";

    echo '<tr bgcolor="'.$table.'"><td><font color="'.getFontColor($i).'">'.$i.'</font></td></tr>';
}

function getFontColor($i) {
    switch( ($i%3) ) {
        case 0:
            return 'blue';
            break;
        case 1:
            return 'red';
            break;
        case 2:
            return 'yellow';
            break;
    }
}
```